# Accessing and using UserClaims in ASP.NET Core Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, claims-based-identity, claims

I am working on ASP.NET Core Web API for the first time and am pretty new to it.
I have added claims and now I want to sort of "read" and access them.

Can someone help me with that?

Comment: Are you using JWT or cookie auth type? Or what?

Comment: @Mateech I am using JWT

Comment: Where do you need to accessing UserClaim? On requesting coming or On generating a token?

Comment: I need to use the var Id = _userManager.GetUserId() where GetUserId() takes ClaimsPrinicpal instance. How do I retrieve that if the claims were added? @HoàngMinhThông

Comment: ms documentation have you tried this?

Answer (score 0):

It`s actually pretty simple. When you create JWT token you add claims to it. It can be userId, his role etc.

So when you setup **authorization with Bearer scheme**, every request that require autorization will be validated. For example this method only will be allowed to reach using jwt token with **claim-type** **role** of **admin** :

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "Bearer")]
public class YourController : ControllerBase
{
    ...
    [HttpGet]
    [Authorize(Roles = "admin")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Method(string id)
    {
    }
    ...
}
```

If token doesn't have required claim you will get `403 Forbidden` response

Comment: I am a bit confused. I need to use the var Id = _userManager.GetUserId() where GetUserId() takes ClaimsPrinicpal instance. How do I retrieve that if the claims were added?

Comment: @Mansi in your controller you can achieve it much easier that way:
`User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)` or other ClaimTypes like email etc.

Comment: I will try this! Thanks @Mateech

Comment: I used User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier) along with HttpContextAccessor dependency injection and it worked for me, thanks :)